# How do I convert "2015-11-06T18:34:07+05:30" string to UTC DateTime object in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, utc, timestamp-with-timezone

I need to convert "2015-11-06T18:34:07+05:30" timestamp coming from  server to DateTime object in C#.Then I need to convert this DateTime to UTC for comparison during synchronization process.And the time zone in this time stamp can vary.So how do I create a timezone independent functionality to get a UTC DateTime object from this timestamp string.

Comment: Use parse : DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("2015-11-06T18:34:07+05:30");  You don't need to convert to UTC.  Dates are automatically stored in the PC as UTC.  Your datetime contains a timezone so it automatically get stored properly and doesn't need conversion.  When displaying a DateTime as a string the PC will convert the UTC stored time to local time using the PC timezone settings.  You only convert if you want to display in a timezone different from local PC timezone setting.  When converting to from a string to DateTime the PC timezone setting is used when a timezone isn't specified.

Comment: @jdweng - Not true.  Without flags, `DateTime.Parse` will adjust the given timestamp to the user's local time zone, not UTC.  You can check `.Kind` on the result and see it will be `Local`.

Comment: Matt : You are saying exactly what I said.  It only appears as if the time was adjusted to local time, but the actual storage in computer is always UTC.   If you change the timezone setting on a computer, the computer doesn't not change the actual time stored in computer just change the way it gets displayed.  Same occurs when going from standard time to daylight savings.  Time isn't changed, only the way the time is displayed.

Comment: Never convert a DataTime to another Timezone it can create problems. The term Convert is issue.  DateTime should always be entered using the timezone where the data was captured.  If the computer where data was entered is not in the same timezone then make sure you include the timezone when entering the data.  If you need to display the DateTime object in a different timezone then what the computer timezone settings then only display in different timezone, never convert the DateTime to another timezone.

Comment: @jdweng - Thanks for you enthusiasm, but several of the things you are saying are incorrect.  Unfortunately, we don't know anything about how these particular values are being *stored* (file, db, etc.) - all we know is that we are given a string in ISO8601 extended format, with an offset, and we are parsing that to a `DateTime` in memory. The `DateTime` object in .Net does **not** always keep its value in UTC.  It has an internal long integer which is a combination of `.Ticks` and `.Kind`.  The ticks are number of 100ns intervals since `0001-01-01 00:00:00`, but they are not adjusted to UTC.

Comment: Note that this is entirely different than then JavaScript `Date` object, or Java's `java.util.Date`, which are indeed based on UTC.  But the .NET `DateTime` object does not have the same implementation or behavior.  Also, I'm not sure why you're bringing up changing the time zone of the computer, as neither the question nor any of my answers would be affected by that.  Because `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` flag is passed, and there's an offset present in the input string, the result is always the correct UTC time. *Without* the flag the result will indeed vary by the computer's time zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2015-11-06T18:34:07+05:30",
               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
               DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Or:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2015-11-06T18:34:07+05:30",
                                  "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                  DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Or:

```
DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2015-11-06T18:34:07+05:30",
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt = dto.UtcDateTime;
```

Or:

```
DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("2015-11-06T18:34:07+05:30",
                                               "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz",
                                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt = dto.UtcDateTime;
```

Of course, there are also the `TryParse` and `TryParseExact` variants, if you need validation.

Personally, I'd recommend keeping it as a `DateTimeOffset` rather than going back to `DateTime`.

There's also [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org):

```
OffsetDateTimePattern pattern = OffsetDateTimePattern.ExtendedIsoPattern;
OffsetDateTime odt = pattern.Parse("2015-11-06T18:34:07+05:30").Value;
DateTimeOffset dto = odt.ToDateTimeOffset();
DateTime dt = dto.UtcDateTime;
```

Comment: Will it work if string is "2015-11-06T18:34:07-02:30"?

Comment: Yes, that's the same [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) extended format.  See also [RFC 3339](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339).

Comment: Be careful with Matt results.  It may not be correct. It is entering time as if it is what enter in universal time not converting to universal time.  For example if you are in NYC at 8:00AM standard time (-5 hours).  Using Matts method The results would be 1:00 PM local time (not UTC).  You really want to enter as local time 8:00AM but display results as 1:00PM.

Comment: @jdweng - Sorry, that's incorrect. In all results from the methods I showed here, the `dt` result has a value in terms of UTC, and has a `Kind` of `DateTimeKind.Utc`. In your example, the results would be 1:00 PM UTC.  [See demo code and results here](https://gist.github.com/mj1856/1b1d986d7765ce2a04b7).

Comment: Matt : I'm correct.  Time should always be entered in the timezone it was entered.  You code is only correct if the time was collected in UTC.  If you want to see a time in UTC then display the time in UTC, don't convert.  If you collect data at 5:00AM EST then enter the time as either 5:00AM EST or 10:00AM UTC.  Don't enter the time as 5:00AM UTC which is wrong.

Comment: I agree with you that you wouldn't enter time as 5 AM UTC if you really meant 5 AM EST, but that's not the input here. In all of these examples, I'm using the same type of input as the OP, which is the local time and local offset. This valid and common (see [RFC3339](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339)§4.2), but you seem to be advocating against it for some reason.  The question and answer are both very specific, clear, and accurate.  Are you trolling me?